# How to render a <svg> inserted by MathJax onto a <canvas>

Tags: canvas, svg, mathjax

I am trying to integrate MathJax into my web-application. And I would like to use MathJax to 
render equations onto a < canvas >

I have been able to coax MathJax into adding a < svg > element to the DOM. But I don't know 
how to go from the < svg > to canvas.ctx.drawImage()

I read some posts about XMLSerializing the < svg >. But when I do the following (locally)

```
svg = $('svg').eq(0)
asStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg) ;
```

I get a "Security Error" from Firefox.

The initial portion of the < svg > MathJax inserted is pasted below

```
<svg><defs id="MathJax_SVG_glyphs"><path id="MJMAIN-24" stroke-width="10" d="M162 187Q162 164 146 149T109
```

So I am wondering if you can help me understand whether

1. The < svg > element looks ok or whether there is something in it that makes XMLSerialization unfeasible?
2. How can I get to ctx.drawImage() starting from the above

Thanks 
Abhinav

Answer (score 1):

XMLSerializer can't be given jQuery objects. I reckon you want

asStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg[0]) ;

So you're not passing some jQuery thing.